# how to get input value in mvc view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in the modal:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="AddDeclineText">
    <div class="row col-12">
        <form class="m-form  col-md-9 col-lg-6">
            <input type="hidden" name="Id" id="Id" value="@Model.Id" class="form-control " />
            <input type="text" id="DeclineText" name="DeclineText"   required class="form-control " />

        </form>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="modal-footer">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="text-align:right;">
        @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="DeclineButton">Save Note</button>*@

        <a asp-action="DeclineQuote" asp-controller="Quotes" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" asp-route-DeclineText="" class="btn btn-default " id="DeclineButton">
            Decline Quote
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary close-button" data-dismiss="modal">@L("Cancel")</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How I can set `asp-route-DeclineText=""` with the input that user will enter?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set `asp-route-DeclineTex` attribute of texbox from input  with Id `DeclineText` in modal?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set the return/posted value for `DeclineText` to ""? Have you looked at the Tag Helper documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1)? What in your code is not working?

Comment: If you want to return multiple values then you need `asp-all-route-data` which allows you to return a dictionary of parameters. See the examples in the documentation referenced above.